# Unable to fit the ansible code in playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts, ansible-template

This is a log file stored in Yaml Format.

My job is to find out the hostname which belongs to hostclass ess, which in this case the answer is host002.

```
hostinfo:
  'host001':
    ip: 192.168.43.10
    hostclass: 'puppet'
  'host002':
    ip: 192.168.43.11
    hostclass: 'ess'
  'host003':
    ip: 192.168.43.21
    hostclass: 'mdb'
```

i got one solution from some friend, but i am unable to fit it my ansible playbook.

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ hostinfo|dictsort|selectattr('1.hostclass', 'equalto', 'ess')|first|first }}"
```

My playbook i am writing, It is wrong but i am not able to figure out how to fit the code in my playbook. Can anyone help me in modifying the code of mine.

```
---

- hosts: somehost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    file: sometext.yaml
    name: sometext

  - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostinfo|dictsort|selectattr('1.hostclass', 'equalto', 'ess')|first|first }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code you've been looking for:

<sup>(on top of the query, you also have a problem with `vars_files`)</sup>

```
tasks:
  - include_vars:
      file: ./sometext.yaml
      name: sometext

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ sometext.hostinfo | dict2items | json_query('[?value.hostclass==`ess`] | [0].key') }}"
```

The last filter in the query returns a single string, if there are multiple hosts with `hostclass` equal to `ess`, you need to change it and it will generate a list.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Ansible in a wrong way. It's possible to write a complicated query (You can use json_query filter for that), but it will be extremely hard to read and maintain.

What you need to do: Instead of using `hostclass: something`, use groups.
Groups are designed for that.

Your inventory should look like this:

```
[puppet]
host001 ip=192.168.43.10
[ess]
host002 ip=192.168.43.11
[mdb]
host003 ip=192.168.43.21

[hostinfo:children]
puppet
ess
mdb
```

After that it's trivial to query groups if you need them (`groups.puppet` for example), and it's easy to access their variables: `(hostvars[groups.puppet][0]).ip`

Comment: Actually this is a log file available in yaml format. so my friend suggested me in doing such way. I just gave a snippet of my log file but it is actually very big..

Comment: Use json_query for that. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter